# In Sql server, Get comma seperated Json keys records for each json data row from the table

Tags: sql-server

In sql server, I have the products table which contains json data records as shown in below. and I want the comma separated keys records for each json row in the table format

**Input:**

JsonData

```
{"add-on":[{"ID":2546978,"ActionType":"Added","Add-On-Name":"tetss","Add-On-Price":"3"},{"ID":2546979,"ActionType":"Added","Add-On-Name":"test Addon2","Add-On-Price":"5"},{"ID":2546980,"ActionType":"Added","Add-On-Name":"tdgd","Add-On-Price":"2"}]}

{"Name":"testing ABC","Menu Column Location":"1"}

{"Features":[{"ActionType":"Added","Feature-Option":"25"}]}

{"add-on":[{"ID":2546993,"ActionType":"Updated"}],"sub add-on":[{"ID":"","ActionType":"Added","Sub-Add-On-Description":"des3"},{"ID":"","ActionType":"Added","Sub-Add-On-Description":"des34"},{"ID":"","ActionType":"Added","Sub-Add-On-Description":"des35"}]}
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ID,ActionType,Add-On-Name,Add-On-Price

Name,Menu Column Location

ActionType,Feature-Option,Features

ID,ActionType,Sub-Add-On-Description,add-on,sub add-on
```

**Note:**
Json keys should not be repeated for each records, All the json key records should get in one table

Comment: what version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: SO is not a *please-do-my-work* platform... Please provide your own effort, describe the issues you've encountered and ask for help... And please provide the SQL Server's version!

Comment: Hi, I am using Sql server 2012